# Understanding how BreadcrumbId is generated

Tags: apache-camel, jms

I was wondering how Camel's `breadcrumbId` is generated?

I've POSTed a message to queue1 using the REST API and this generates a message with messageId value "X".

I've then tested the following very simple routes consuming from one queue and sending to another.

```
queue1 --> queue2
queue2 --> queue3
queue3 --> queue4
queue4 --> queue5
```

A `breadcrumbId` is generated in the first route with value "X".

In each route each message gets a new MessageId as per the JMS spec but the `breadcrumbId` remains the same.

The word "breadcrumb" gives me the impression it should change each route/exchange to allow you to trace back through the messages?

But it seems to be the MessageId of the very first message?

I can't find a description of how it is actually generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Camel [doc](https://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/mdc-logging.html)

> breadcrumbId - An unique id used for tracking messages across
>   transports

I think the value for the message is generated during the first camel processing from `MessageId`, and then the existing one is used.